# Upload video to SharePoint library by code

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-2016

I am making a app for SharePoint and have a form with several inputs for text and for files as well. The input for files works fine for regular files such as Word, Excel, PowerPoint, images etc... but wont work with videos. Is it possible to upload a video to a document library by code? Or cant you do that simply because the files is usually to big and would take long to upload?

The files is of the type `HttpPostedFileBase` and sent by a normal mvc form.

And this is the code for uploading it to the folder

```
FileCreationInformation attachFileInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
attachFileInfo.ContentStream = pNewRequest.FileToUpload1.InputStream;
attachFileInfo.Url = Path.GetFileName(pNewRequest.FileToUpload1.FileName);
newFolder.Files.Add(attachFileInfo);
```

Comment: By default SP's file size limit is 50mb. Are you maybe trying this with a file that is too large?

Comment: @JimYarbro I made a 1sec video with my phone and that didnt work so i guess  the problem isnt the size? A solution but very unnecessary and bad one is to upload the video to Youtube and just save the url in a SP list.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this StackExchange answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/157170/csom-how-to-get-video-file), SP videos are organized in special VideoSet folders which seem to be similar to doc sets.

You said you're using MVC to submit the files so I'm assuming you're using CSOM on an external server. [Here's an example for handling video uploads via CSOM](http://www.letsharepoint.com/how-to-upload-video-file-with-metadata-using-csom-in-sharepoint-online-office-365/).